# SQL-Server select rows that different between 3 columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have table with 3 columns.
For example:
Table test

```
test1|test2|test3
-----------------
ab   |a    |aba
----------------
a    |b    |aa
----------------
b    |a    |ba
```

I want all rows that column test1 + test2 not equal test3

Continue from above example: I want to get just the row 2 with the columns a|b|aa.

I try the follwing code:

```
select distinct * from DB.dbo.test l where (l.test1+ l.test2) <> l.test3;
```

But it doesn't work well.
It's return me all the rows

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: It's look fine. Make sure that there are no empty space in your data

Comment: What do you get if you `select l.test1+ l.test2`? Do you get for example `ab` as you'd expect, or something like `a b` with an extra space?

Comment: your attempt should work,make sure you check space and you trim as well ..just in case

Comment: From select l.test1+ l.test2 I get ab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you have leading spaces:

```
CREATE TABLE T (test1 varchar(40), test2 varchar(40), test3 varchar(40));

INSERT INTO T VALUES
('ab ', 'a', 'aba'),
('a ', 'b', 'aa'),
('b ', 'a', 'ba');

SELECT *
FROM T
WHERE RTRIM(LTRIM(Test1)) + RTRIM(LTRIM(Test2)) != RTRIM(LTRIM(Test3));
```

**[Demo](http://rextester.com/WCTCI84429)**